# How to compose a regex to find dot and numbers or nothing?

Tags: regex

I need to find substrings of the following format:

```
.000<digits>
```

where the zeros' quantity may be from 0 (i.e., without zeros after the dot) to 3 and digits quantity starts from 0. But, if there is no the <digits> part, the regex should match nothing. I.e., I need to find the `.123`, `.01`, `.0001`, but not `.000`, `.`, `.00001`.

Is it possible to do this with regex?

**UPDATE:**

The <digits> part should be started with non-zero, but it may contain zero inside. Though, it's can be seen from the prev. text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
\.0{0,3}[1-9]\d*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jz4TkH/1)

This matches a dot followed by 0 to 3 zeroes followed by one non-zero digit and allows for 0 or more digits afterwards before end position.

Comment: Hey! How did you do that?.. I was trying (almost) the same expressions, but with no luck... By the way, it looks like the `$` is non-mandatory.

Comment: Yes `$` is not required here, we can replace `$` with `\b` for word boundary